# Pycaret installation on Mac unsuccessful via pip

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pip, pycaret

I navigate to the python3.11 folder and execute the `pip3 install pycaret` (also tried `pip install pycaret`) command to install `pycaret`.

-The installation goes on for a long time and it struck to try installing different versions of `pandas` from 1.4.4 thru to 1.3.3 (see attached **Photo1**).

-Finally it gives up with errors `Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully` and `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'` and `This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip`. See **Photo2**.

I already have pandas 2.0.3 , numpy 1.25.1 and wheel 0.38.4 installed on my computer. Any suggestion about what may I be missing?

**Photo1:**
[image]

**Photo2:**
[image]

Comment: hmmm it seems like you have anothe rversion of python just inside of this yt pip build environment folder. How many python installations do you have on your computer, and how many of them have numpy?

Comment: @Mark is there someway to determine where/how many python installations are on my computer?